# Jasmine trying to read property that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have an extremely simple component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'loading',
    templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./loading.component.scss']
})
export class LoadingComponent {
}
```

which just displays a static loading logo. No interactivity at all. I wrote a test just to test its instantiation:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { LoadingComponent } from './loading.component';

describe('LoadingComponent', () => {
    let component: LoadingComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoadingComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ LoadingComponent ]
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoadingComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

In Firefox, this test throws an error: `j is undefined`, and in Chromium browsers I see `Cannot read property 'startTime' of undefined`. The template is simply:

```html
Sample Text
```

for the sake of figuring out what's going on. So there's no mention of 'startTime' anywhere in those three files - what's going on??

### Note

I do use `startTime` properties in other components, but I can't figure out how/why that would matter.

### Edit

I've been able to get this error to disappear by just adding:

```js
afterAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
});
```

to every single test in the project. I'm leaving the question open because I have no idea:

1. Why this works/what the underlying problem was
2. If I'm swinging a heavier axe than I need to - would adding it to only one test suffice?

Comment: are you using `LoadingComponent` already in the app? if so, its likely being instantiated thus the error.

Comment: I am, but the error is coming specifically from the `LoadingComponent should exist` test. Doesn't that mean the error is being thrown from there?

Comment: No not necessarily, I've come across this many times before(including today).  Start with adding `f` to describe. Your main `describe` will now be `fdescribe('LoadingComponent',...` if this single describe succeeds you can now move on to checking the scope of testing outside the loader.spec

Comment: So I was actually able to get this and other random `[object Object] was thrown` errors that popped up sporadically in all tests to go away by adding `afterAll(()=>{TestBed.resetTestingModule();});` to every test. But I have no clue why that works or what it even does, really.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is definitely not coming from component and spec file you have posted. The error you are seeing is most likely coming from a component that does an async operation and the error occurs after the spec that instantiated it has already finished.

First off put an f in frontof the describes of this spec file.

```
fdescribe('LoadingComponent', () => {
```

This will cause the spec runner to only run this file. You will see that it passes fine.

Next you want to remove the f and the search your project for startTime, try running specs for components that use the property startTime one at a time.

If you can't locate it then put an x in front of the describes of them one at a time, eventually you will find which one is causing the error as it wont happen when you have an x on the spec that causes the error.

Any specs that do async function should use the async function so that it waits for all async activity to finish before moving on to the next spec.

Comment: "Any specs that do async function should use the async function so that it waits for all async activity to finish before moving on to the next spec." Where? `describe('Thing', async() => ...`, `beforeEach(async() =>`, or `it('should do something', async() => ...`? Or all three?

Comment: @suckoverflow : did `fdescribe` stopped the error while running tests for that component?